# Is there a JavaScript event that is triggered when a field type's settings html is displayed within Matrix?

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

Google Maps for Craft has a settings page that uses JavaScript that aids the user in setting up their Google Maps field. So the user can set a default center and zoom for the map, and they do this by manipulating a map in the settings page. All works fine when creating a standard field. I used the `$(document).ready()` method to trigger my code, but since Matrix creates these fields after the DOM has already triggered that event, my code isn't getting instantiated. Matrix for EE has a similar callback function that is triggered, so I assume Matrix for Craft has the same thing.

Any code examples for listening for when new Matrix fields are created? I tried browsing through the existing field type code and `MatrixConfigurator.js` but couldn't find any examples yet.

Comment: Sorry Justin, was responding from my phone, and totally missed that this is for the _settings’_ HTML, not your input’s HTML.  Can you send me your field type - support@buildwithcraft.com - and I’ll see if there’s something we can do to make this easier.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no event for it, but any JS you include using [craft()->templates->includeJs()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#includeJs-detail) from your field type's getSettingsHtml() method will get fired each time a new Matrix sub-field is created, so **if you code your field type correctly** with properly namespaced inputs] IDs/names, no event will be needed.

The thing about Matrix is, there’s no way to predict what the actual input IDs/names are going to be when they are added to the DOM, as they will be run through [TemplatesService::namespaceInputs()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#namespaceInputs-detail) with the namespace `blockTypes[__BLOCK_TYPE__][fields][__FIELD__][typesettings]`, and those “__BLOCK_TYPE__” and “__FIELD__” placeholders are replaced dynamically by MatrixConfigurator’s Javascript before adding the settings HTML to the DOM.

Regular field settings get namespaced too, but in a more predictable way (their namespace will always be `types[FieldTypeClassHandle]`), so it can be tempting to just hard-code the namespaced IDs directly into your Javascript, like this:

```php
$js = "\$('#types-FieldTypeClassHandle-myInputId')" // ...
```

Matrix’s unpredictability shows why it’s important to **not** do that, and instead always use [TemplatesService::namespaceInputId()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#namespaceInputId-detail) and [namespaceInputName()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#namespaceInputName-detail) whenever you need to reference an input’s ID or name from your Javascript:

```php
$namespacedId = craft()->templates->namespaceInputId('myInputId');

$js = "\$('#{$namespacedId}')" // ...
```

When you let TemplatesService generate the namespaced IDs/names for you, you can be sure that it will always give you an ID/name that will match whatever the actual ID/name will be in the DOM.

Comment: That's the method I am currently using to include JS. My FT works 100% with the `getInputHtml()` method, but it's not in the `getSettingsHtml()` method. I will give it a shot with the logic you mentioned and I will you know how it goes.

Comment: After looking more into this, I did make some headway on this and got it working better than before but still not there yet. I really need a JS event to be fired when the field type settings are show, ideally along with the parent DOM node so I can traverse through it. I can explain more about "why" I need this if necessary, but you can file this is as a request. Should be easy enough to add to the JS you already have.